# Is Spanish a subset of French?

Tags: latin, apprentissage, espagnol

I heard someone say "if (as a speaker of English) you learn French, you get Spanish for free".

Is this true? Is Spanish mostly a subset of French?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, since it is about comparing two romance languages it might be better on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) where they would probably better take into account the OP's mother tongue (English) into the learning process.

Comment: @Laure The question might perhaps be viewed as a caracteristic of French as  it relates to the romance languages, considering the nature of French as what is to be made more precise through a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very dubious assertion; I know for certain that  speaking French fluently is not going to make a conversation in Spanish intelligible at all to you, nor one either  in Portugese or Italian. It must be taken very generally: you'll find often the same latin roots but that's about all in the way of a solid similarity. For instance, whereas in French and English you have just one verb "to be" in Spanish you have two (ser, estar); you find the forms of the French verb "être" (sont, sera, serais, être, est, …) in those two verbs but very much modified and that's not going to help: the precise combinations of those forms are made according to quantities of different rules; for instance when you use personal pronouns with verbs in French, you don't use any in Spanish (« Il parle fort. », « Habla fuerte. »). Here you do find that "fort" is "fuerte" but in spite of the same latin root, you'll never know that before you've actually learned this correspondence.